Sign Error in derivation of Faraday 2-form
The electromagnetic field tensor $F_{\mu\nu} $ in component form is:
$$
F_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{E_x}{c} & \frac{E_y}{c} & \frac{E_z}{c} \\
-\frac{E_x}{c} & 0 & -B_z & B_y \\
-\frac{E_y}{c} & B_z & 0 & -B_x \\
-\frac{E_z}{c} & -B_y & B_x & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where:

$E_x, E_y, E_z$ are the components of the electric field.
$ B_x, B_y, B_z $ are the components of the magnetic field.

The Faraday 2-form is defined as
\begin{align*}
    F &= \sum_{\mu} \sum_{\nu} \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu} \\
      & = \frac{1}{2} F_{11} dt \wedge dt + \frac{1}{2} F_{12} dt \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} F_{13} dt \wedge dy +  \frac{1}{2} F_{14} dt \wedge dz  \\
      &+ \frac{1}{2} F_{21} dx \wedge dt + \frac{1}{2} F_{22} dx \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} F_{23} dx \wedge dy +  \frac{1}{2} F_{24} dx \wedge dz\\ 
      &+\frac{1}{2} F_{31} dy \wedge dt + \frac{1}{2} F_{32} dy \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} F_{33} dy \wedge dy +  \frac{1}{2} F_{34} dy \wedge dz \\
      &+ \frac{1}{2} F_{41} dz \wedge dt + \frac{1}{2} F_{42} dz \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} F_{43} dz \wedge dy +  \frac{1}{2} F_{44} dz \wedge dz  \\\\
      %
      %
      & = \frac{1}{2} 0  \cdot 0 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{E_x}{c} dt \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} \frac{E_y}{c} dt \wedge dy +  \frac{1}{2} \frac{E_z}{c} dt \wedge dz  \\
      &+ \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{E_x}{c} \right) dx \wedge dt + \frac{1}{2} 0  \cdot 0 + \frac{1}{2} (-B_z) dx \wedge dy +  \frac{1}{2} B_y dx \wedge dz\\ 
      &+\frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{E_y}{c}\right) dy \wedge dt + \frac{1}{2} B_z dy \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} 0  \cdot 0 +  \frac{1}{2} (-B_x) dy \wedge dz \\
      &+ \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{E_z}{c}\right) dz \wedge dt + \frac{1}{2} (-B_y) dz \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} -B_x dz \wedge dy +  \frac{1}{2} 0  \cdot 0 \\\\
      %
      %
      & =  \left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{E_x}{c}  dt \wedge dx +\frac{1}{2} \frac{E_x}{c} dt \wedge dx  \right)+ \left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{E_y}{c} dt \wedge dy  +\frac{1}{2} \frac{E_y}{c} dt \wedge dy  \right)\\
      &+ \left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{E_z}{c} dt \wedge dz +\frac{1}{2} \frac{E_z}{c} dt \wedge dz \right) + \left(\frac{1}{2} B_z dx \wedge dy  + \frac{1}{2} B_z dx \wedge dy \right) \\ 
      &+\left( \frac{1}{2} B_y dz \wedge dx + \frac{1}{2} B_y dz \wedge dx\right)  + \left( \frac{1}{2} B_x dy \wedge dz + \frac{1}{2} B_x dy \wedge dz
      \right) \\\\
      %
      %
      &= \frac{E_x}{c} dt \wedge dx  + \frac{E_y}{c} dt \wedge dy + \frac{E_z}{c} dt \wedge dz + B_z dx \wedge dy + B_y dz \wedge dx + B_x dy \wedge dz 
\end{align*}
Is this right? It looks right to me. I felt ok with it. But both Wikipedia and Misner Wheeler and Thorne have
$$   F = \frac{E_x}{c}dx  \wedge dt  + \frac{E_y}{c} dy \wedge dt + \frac{E_z}{c} dz \wedge dt + B_z dx \wedge dy + B_y dz \wedge dx + B_x dy \wedge dz $$
See here for the wikipedia discussion.

I think $F_{0i}=-E_i$ rather than $E_i$...that will solve the ambiguity

@KP99 agreed. but then is this definition on wikipedia inconsistent. i originally had that and then shifted it because i though i had the form of the tensor wrong
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor
if that's the case, then yes that clears everything up

I haven't looked at MWT yet but I think you should pay attention to sign convention being used (if it's+--- or -+++). I think you are using+---
